# Proof of lemma from Hong's article about multi-threaded max flow algorithm

Tags: parallel-computing, network-flow

I'm struggling to prove Lemma 3 and Lemma 4 from an article about parallel version of push-relabel algorithm: [A lock-free multi-threaded algorithm for the maximum flow problem](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4536352).

> **Lemma 3.** Any trace of two push and/or lift operations is equivalent to either a stage-clean trace or a stage-stepping trace.

And

> **Lemma 4.** For any trace of three or more push and/or lift operations, there exists an equivalent trace consisting of a sequence
>   of non-overlapping traces, each of which is either stage-clean or
>   stage-stepping.

Pdf version of the article can be found [here](http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~wls77/weston/projects/cis598/hong.pdf)

Comment: "The proof of Lemma 3 is straightforward. We simply need to enumerate all the possible pairs of operations that might be interleaved and derive an equivalent trace (either stage-clean or stage-stepping) for each such pair.", reads the article. Have you tried enumerating all the possible pairs of operations?

Comment: The way I see it: we have a list of instructions that are executed in parallel, the number of possible traces (the author uses the term _trace_ to define the order in which instructions from the threads are executed in real time) is pretty big and impractical to be analyzed one by one. I don't understand how to approach the problem by looking at operations. So lets take (push, push) pair, how can I prove that all the possible traces of two pushes on two different threads are equivalent (have the same consequence) to either a _stage-clean trace_ or a _stage-stepping trace_? What am I missing?

Comment: You may write a computer program that lists all possible cases.